# Regex for excluding files with specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Hey I have a list of files

- B123245.xml
- B123245-ext.xml
- 1234W01.xml
- 1234W01-ext.xml

Now I need a regular expression filter only the files without -ext in the name.

I tried already this `^.+(?!-ext)\.xml$`
but it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This part `(?!-ext)` should be  `^(?!.*-ext)`

Comment: I tried `^(?!-ext).+\.xml$` This is still matiching all files

Comment: I updated the comment, it should be `^(?!.*-ext).+\.xml$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your exact needs, but if you want to exclude those file where "-ext" is right before the xml extension I think you could use:

```
^.+(?<!-ext)\.xml$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XANhCV/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `.+` - 1+ character apart from newline.
- `(?<!-ext)` - A negative lookbehind to assert position isn't preceded by "-ext".
- `\.xml` - Match a literal dot and "xml".
- `$` - End string anchor.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of user 'The fourth bird' I found out the correct structure.

Here is the correct result

```
^(?!.*-ext).+\.xml$
```